# Difference between my python script and the perl script to calculate throughput and what does granularity mean?

Tags: python, perl, ns2, throughput

So i recently wrote a python script which parses an ns2 trace file and calculates throughput. I also have a perl script that I downloaded from the internet that does the same thing but a little differently. I am having a hard time understanding what granularity(used in the perl script) means. Can someone please help me? Thanks. The codes are provided below.

```
trace = open('window_size_23.tr' , 'r')
s = 0
prev = 0.0
start = 0.0
end = 0.0
for line in trace:
    words = line.split(' ')
    if line.startswith('r') and 'tcp' in line and words[3] == '1' and 
words[8] == '0.0' and words[9] == '1.0':

        s = s + int(words[5])
        if prev == 0.0:
            start = float(words[1])
        prev = float(words[1])
end = prev
throughput = (s*8.0)/((end - start)*1000000)
print throughput, start, end
```

Here's the perl script

```
$infile=$ARGV[0];
    $destnode=$ARGV[1];
    $fromport=$ARGV[2];
    $toport=$ARGV[3];
    $granularity=$ARGV[4];

    $sum=0;
    $grantsum=0;
    $clock=0;

    open (DATA,"<$infile") || die "Can't open $infile $!";  
    while (<DATA>) 
    {
        @x = split(' ');
        if ($x[1]-$clock <= $granularity)
        {
            if ($x[0] eq 'r') 
            { 
                if ($x[3] eq $destnode && $x[8] eq $fromport && $x[9] 
                eq $toport) 
                { 
                    if ($x[4] eq 'tcp') 
                    {
                        $sum=$sum+$x[5];
                        $grantsum=$grantsum+$x[5];
                    }
                }
            }
       }
       else
       {   
           $throughput=0.000008*$sum/$granularity;
           print STDOUT "$clock $throughput\n";

           $clock=$clock+$granularity;

           if ($x[0] eq 'r' && $x[3] eq $destnode && $x[8] eq 
           $fromport && $x[9] eq $toport && $x[4] eq 'tcp')
           {
                $sum=$x[5];
                $grantsum=$grantsum+$x[5];
           }
           else
           {
               $sum=0;
           }

           while ($x[1]-$clock > $granularity)
           {
               print STDOUT "$clock 0.0\n";
               $clock=$clock+$granularity;
           }
      }   
 }

$throughput=0.000008*$sum/$granularity;
print STDOUT "$clock $throughput\n";
$clock=$clock+$granularity;

print STDERR "Avg throughput $fromport - $toport = ",
         0.000008*$grantsum/$clock,"MBytes/sec \n";

close DATA;

exit(0);
```

Comment: `$granularity` Would be a variable name, which you input from cmdline when you run the script using switches and it will then be coming from `$ARGV[4];` Here I would say that the granularity will be in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Google, what is granularity
https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+what+is+granularity

. [Example](https://books.google.dk/books?id=CXENDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=ns2%20what%20is%20granularity&source=bl&ots=zyXxTUjbPt&sig=4b5VBvfWFRh7bmHAz5xA-4BDhdM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=%200ahUKEwjgsv2VuqLXAhWElxoKHZlmBtQQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=ns2%20what%20is%20granularity&f=false) →  " .. granularity (i.e. **different level of abstraction**) .. "

. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Bandwidth_Estimation_in_ns212
→  " .. with fine granularity timestamp (milli if not microseconds)."

All ns2 awk, perl scripts https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNdkdRalVpWk56MmM/view?usp=sharing

Analyzing tool (awk, python): APP-Tool https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

Example, APP-Tool → throughput → image

[image]